# How to reveal what caused Angular ChangeDetection using ZoneJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection, zonejs

I would like to find out, what is causing Change Detection cycles in my Angular (version 8 - I can't upgrade now) application. **I would like to patch or intercept ZoneJS** so I can see what has triggered the CD cycle.

(For example: that `tick()` has been started by HTML input keyup event listener.)

This is my main.ts file:

```js
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(moduleRef => {
  const applicationRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
  const componentRef = applicationRef.components[0];
  enableDebugTools(componentRef);
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

And this is monkey patched `tick()` function to see application ticks.

```js
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private readonly translate: TranslateService,
    applicationRef: ApplicationRef
  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('cz');

    const originalTick = applicationRef.tick;
    applicationRef.tick = function(): any {
      console.log('TICK');

      return originalTick.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }
}
```

With this setup, I can see **two ticks** for **every keyboard input** in an input text with `[(ngModel)]` (and four template checks using `{{test()}} / console.log('Template Check')` in Component). I would expect only **single tick** and **two template checks**.

I found I can use `TaskTrackingZoneSpec` [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/zone-js-for-angular-devs-573d89bbb890) but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Keydown and keypressed events are firing - thus 2 checks as change detection cycle is invoked on user input envets (and xhr requests)

Comment: Please see here for a quick showcase: https://stackblitz.com/github/felikf/a12-test/tree/test/change-detection open console (right bottom click on console link) and edit the text area, see one TICK for each keyprees. That is for a  clean A12 repo. In my work repo with Angular 8, there are two ticks for each keypress, what is I need to understand where is the difference:)

Comment: Try the same on your your version of angular. Maybe it will be the same. Something might have changed - its 4 major versions after all.